# SQL Server Return all fields in TableA when not matched and only TableB when matched

Tags: sql, exists

I have two tables where I want to return all data in Table A when it has no match in Table B and all data in Table B when it matches with Table A. I have solved this but it is ugly.

```
create table TEST.A 
(TYPE varchar(50), AMOUNT INT, DESCRIPTION varchar(50), DATE datetime2)

create table TEST.B 
(TYPE2 varchar(50), AMOUNT2 INT, DESCRIPTION2 varchar(50), DATE2 datetime2)

insert into TEST.A  values
('apples',3,'fruit','2016-12-31'),
('bananas',2,'fruit','2016-12-15'),
('pears',7,'fruit','2016-12-11')

insert into TEST.B  values
('shop2',1,'shops','2016-12-31')
```

Result required;

[image]

Here the ugly code:

```
SELECT TYPE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DATE, NULL TYPE2,NULL AMOUNT2,NULL DESCRPTION2,NULL DATE2
FROM TEST.A
EXCEPT
SELECT A.*, NULL TYPE2,NULL AMOUNT2,NULL DESCRPTION2,NULL DATE2
FROM TEST.A a
JOIN TEST.B b ON a.DATE = b.DATE2
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TYPE2, AMOUNT2, DESCRIPTION2, DATE2
FROM TEST.B
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I am missing something here, who can give me a pretty answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the first part with `EXCEPT` as follows

```
SELECT TYPE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DATE, NULL TYPE2,NULL AMOUNT2,NULL DESCRPTION2,NULL DATE2
FROM TEST.A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM TEST.B b WHERE a.DATE = b.DATE
)
```

and it is possible to use `NOT IN` as well, however, you have to be carefull with NULL values.

```
SELECT TYPE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DATE, NULL TYPE2,NULL AMOUNT2,NULL DESCRPTION2,NULL DATE2
FROM TEST.A
WHERE a.DATE NOT IN(
    SELECT b.DATE FROM TEST.B b WHERE b.Date IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: `SELECT TYPE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DATE, NULL TYPE2,NULL AMOUNT2,NULL DESCRPTION2,NULL DATE2
FROM TEST.A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM TEST.B b WHERE a.DATE = b.DATE2
)
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TYPE2, AMOUNT2, DESCRIPTION2, DATE2
FROM TEST.B`